# Memory leak at Autorelease pool in Iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

I am getting leak at [pool release];

My code here is:

```
#pragma mark UISearchBarDelegate delegate methods


- (void)performSearch:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
{

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

artistName= [aSearchBar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
if ([artistName length] > 0) 
{

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    LyricsAppDelegate* appDelegate =  (LyricsAppDelegate*) [ [UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    artistsList=[appDelegate doSearch:artistName ];
    [theTableView reloadData];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;


    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;


    [aSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
else
{
    [aSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
[NSThread exit];
[pool release]; 

}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
{
@try {
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(performSearch:) toTarget:self withObject:aSearchBar];
    [aSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"\n caught an exception");
}
@finally {
}
}
```

Here I am getting leak at [pool release]; in performSearch method.

How can I solve this.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to release pool before you exit current thread?

```
...
[pool release]; 
[NSThread exit];
```

**Edit:** From NSThread -exit reference:

> Invoking this method should be avoided
>   as it does not give your thread a
>   chance to clean up any resources it
>   allocated during its execution.

Do you really need to call this function BTW?

Comment: yes I tries as up to ur suggestion but now it showing leak at the line:

artistName= [aSearchBar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Comment: When I taken off the thread the search is very slow actually I am getting the data from the parser.

Comment: I mean why you need to exit from thread using [NSThread exit] function? Did you try just remove [NSThread exit] call?

Comment: I tried it by removing the thread totally....actually I called the method performSelector using thread.now I an not using any thread to call it and i directly calling the method using self by passing searchbar as an argument.

Comment: You can run this method using performSelectorInBackground: - it will run your method in separate thread but you will not need to mess with NSThread objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Vladimir's answer pointing out the autorelease pool leak, both artistName & artistList are missing a `release` message before you set them to a new value (otherwise the old object is leaked), and a `retain` message afterwards (so the new object sticks around when the autorelease pool is drained).

```
[artistsList release];
artistsList = [[appDelegate doSearch:artistName] retain];
```

Comment: thanks very much Vladimir and tedge its working fine I totally removed the thread from my code.